# Why is calling a class method in the constructor causing the program to hang?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, winapi

I am trying to use Qt to create a GUI to wrap Rip Grep as a project to become more familiar with Qt, C++, and the Win32 APIs. I have a class called `RunCommand` I'm writing to contain the functionality of running a command line program and capturing its output to a string for use in the GUI. In `RunCommand`, I have some methods that encapsulate different parts of the work `RunCommand` has to do. I'm trying to have the constructor do all the work by calling the methods. The issue is that when I call the methods from the constructor, the program hangs indefinitely, but when I copy and paste the code from the methods into the constructor directly, things work as expected. What am I missing here?

I noticed that the code runs fine if the method is pasted directly into the constructor. `RunCommand` is started when the user clicks the `helloButton`. I have a message I'm writing to a `QTextEdit` widget to debug that I've placed in the class method called by the constructor before any actual code in that method runs and then returns immediately, and I still experience the hang, so I think the issue lies in the way I'm calling the method, not in what the method is trying to do. I am able to write other text to the `QTextEdit` widget if I don't make class method calls from the constructor.

easyrip.cpp

```cpp
#include "easyrip.h"
#include "ui_easyrip.h"
#include "runcommand.h"
#include "synchapi.h"

using namespace std;

EasyRip::EasyRip(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::EasyRip)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    connect(ui->helloButton, &QPushButton::pressed, this, &EasyRip::testHello);
}

EasyRip::~EasyRip()
{
    delete ui;
}

void EasyRip::testHello()
{
    ui->cmdDisplay->setText("Running rg help command...");
    string cmdOutput = "";
    RunCommand(R"(C:\Users\Name\OneDrive\RipGrep\rg.exe --help)", cmdOutput);
    ui->cmdDisplay->setText(cmdOutput.c_str());
}
```

runcommand.h

```cpp
#ifndef CMDRUNNER_H
#define CMDRUNNER_H

#include <Windows.h> 
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <string>

class RunCommand
{
public:
    RunCommand(const std::string cmd, std::string& cmdOutput);
    ~RunCommand();

private:
    void CreateChildProcess(const std::string cmd, std::string& cmdOutput);
    void ReadFromPipe(std::string& cmdOutput);

    HANDLE _hChildStd_OUT_Rd = nullptr;
    HANDLE _hChildStd_OUT_Wr = nullptr;
};

#endif
```

runcommand.cpp

```cpp
#include "runcommand.h"

constexpr int BUFSIZE = 4096;

using namespace std;

RunCommand::~RunCommand()
{
   CloseHandle(_hChildStd_OUT_Rd);
   CloseHandle(_hChildStd_OUT_Wr);
}

// Runs cmd and returns the command output on cmdOutput.
RunCommand::RunCommand(const string cmd, string& cmdOutput)
{
   // Set the bInheritHandle flag so pipe handles are inherited by the child process.
   SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr;
   saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
   saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
   saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = nullptr;

   // Create a pipe for the child process's STDOUT.
   if (!CreatePipe(&_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, &_hChildStd_OUT_Wr, &saAttr, 0))
   {
      cmdOutput.assign("Error: StdoutRd CreatePipe failed");
      return;
   }

   // Ensure the read handle to the pipe for STDOUT is not inherited.
   // We want the child process to only inherit the write end of the PIPE
   // we created above. Then it can write to the inherited write end of 
   // the PIPE, and we can read from the non-inherited read end.
   if (!SetHandleInformation(_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, FALSE))
   {
      cmdOutput.assign("Error: Stdout SetHandleInformation failed");
      return;
   }

   // If "Debug point" is assigned to cmdOutput here and returned, 
   // the text is successfully displayed in the QTextEdit widget,
   // and the code does not hang.

   // Create the child process.
   // I have also tried calling this as RunCommand::CreateChildProcess
   this->CreateChildProcess(cmd, cmdOutput);

   // Read the standard output from the child process.
   this->ReadFromPipe(cmdOutput);
}

// Create a child process that uses the previously created pipes for STDOUT.
void RunCommand::CreateChildProcess(const string cmd, string& cmdOutput)
{
   cmdOutput.assign("Debug point"); // Issue: Never reaches this line.
   return;

   ...
}

// Read output from the child process's pipe for STDOUT
// and copy it to the referenced std::string.
// Stop when there is no more data. 
void RunCommand::ReadFromPipe(std::string& cmdOutput)
{
   ...
}
```

Expected result: The contents of the `rg --help` command are copied to the cmdOutput string, and then displayed in the QTextEdit widget.

Actual result: The program hangs indefinitely and needs to be force closed when the RunCommand constructor tries to call class methods.

Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr;` -- You failed to initialize `saAttr`.  You are now using a half-baked `saAttr` and passing it to the Windows API.  Try `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr {};` instead.

Comment: *I'm trying to have the constructor do all the work by calling the methods.* -- This is not a good idea, IMO.  A constructor should do minimal work.

Comment: Hi @PaulMcKenzie, thanks for the advice. I'll make sure to initialize `saAttr`. As far as the constructor doing work, here is my intention. I wanted this to be a sort of run once and done scenario per instantiation. I originally had a Run() method that would do the work after being the class was instantiated, but I don't want to make it seem like Run() can be called multiple times because I'm still a bit shy about resource management in C++. Do you have any recommendations for a design improvement in this case?

Comment: I would probably have SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES as a member, set the values, and probably have the command to run as members.  Then a `RunCommand()::run()` member function would be invoked to do the work.  As to the initialization, I see that `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` only has 3 members, but you shouldn't code this way, for safety.  Always zero-initialize Windows API structs, because you never know when the struct may add members or change in some way.  There are other Windows API structs where you can't get away with setting only members you care about.

Comment: From the way you are making use of this class in "easyrip.cpp," I would suggest that what you are really looking for is implementing a "static member function." Static member functions don't require the class to be instantiated at all, which would solve the constructor hang you're experiencing, while also implying that the object can't be "Run()" multiple times.

Comment: I think I've run into a similar hang before. The problem seems to be that a class constructor executes during an object's lifetime where the object isn't exactly fully constructed yet. The point of a constructor method is to do all the initialization necessary for bringing the object into existence. Calling member functions that require the object to be fully up and usable is an anti-pattern to be avoided.

Comment: I think this is not the issue about object's lifetime. It is usually safe to call any member function from within a constructor because the object has been completely set up prior to the execution of the first line of user code. However, be careful when you call virtual functions in constructors. see [Virtual Functions in Constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/s16xw1a8%28v%3dvs.140%29#virtual-functions-in-constructors).

Comment: I haven't got the hang on when I call the class method in constructor as the same with you in debug mode, but in release, I also cannot reach in the function CreateChildProcess(), but actually, the `string.assign("Debug point")` has been executed and I got the correct string(also didn't hang on). I guess it's possible that you hung on while you were reading the pipe. Make sure close the useless size of the pipe in the both processes. (Close write handle here and close all the pipe handles when exit child process.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To follow up, I eventually figured out that the issue was not caused by calling the methods in the constructor. It's technically fine to do that, even if it isn't a recommended approach.

The real issue was happening in `ReadFromPipe`. For some reason, the child process was not exiting after running, which caused the logic that was reading to hang forever waiting for some kind of end of file signal. I never saw `"Debug point"` in the UI because even though I returned immediately from `CreateChildProcess` after setting the text, I forgot to also return immediately from `ReadFromPipe`. The code hang in `ReadFromPipe` means I never saw the debug text in the UI.

Thanks for all the helpful suggestions on how to improve, they were really useful in helping me figure out what was going wrong.